# How to render ConTeXt source code example with rendered result in ConTeXt

Tags: context, context-mkiv

I need to place source code example in `ConTeXt` with compiled result.

```
code:
  ConTeXt code example 
result:
  compiled result
```

I can do it like that:

```
\mainlanguage[ru]

\usemodule  [simplefonts][size=12pt]
\setmainfont[dejavusans][expansion=quality,protrusion=quality]
\setmonofont[monaco][expansion=quality,protrusion=quality]

\usemodule [vim]
\defineframedtext [CODEBLOCK][background=color,backgroundcolor=lightgray,
                              width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-1cm),frame=off,offset=2mm]
\definevimtyping[TEX][syntax=context,before=\startCODEBLOCK,after=\stopCODEBLOCK]
\defineframedtext [CODERESULT][width=\textwidth,frame=off,offset=2mm]
\definedescription[descr][indenting=1cm,indentnext=yes,location=right,
  width=\textwidth,distance=\dimexpr(1cm-\textwidth),align={width,stretch}]

\starttext


\startdescr{code:} \hfill
\startTEX
\ConTeXt
\stopTEX
\stopdescr

\startdescr{result:} \hfill
\startCODERESULT
\ConTeXt
\stopCODERESULT
\stopdescr

\stoptext
```

but code duplication is not very convenient.

I tried this:

```
\mainlanguage[ru]

\usemodule  [simplefonts][size=12pt]
\setmainfont[dejavusans][expansion=quality,protrusion=quality]
\setmonofont[monaco][expansion=quality,protrusion=quality]

\usemodule [vim]
\defineframedtext [CODEBLOCK][background=color,backgroundcolor=lightgray,
                              width=\dimexpr(\textwidth-1cm),frame=off,offset=2mm]
\definevimtyping[TEX][syntax=context,before=\startCODEBLOCK,after=\stopCODEBLOCK]
\defineframedtext [CODERESULT][width=\textwidth,frame=off,offset=2mm]
\definedescription[descr][indenting=1cm,indentnext=yes,location=right,
  width=\textwidth,distance=\dimexpr(1cm-\textwidth),align={width,stretch}]

\def\texsample#1{
\startdescr{code:} \hfill
\startTEX
#1
\stopTEX
\stopdescr

\startdescr{result:} \hfill
\startCODERESULT
#1
\stopCODERESULT
\stopdescr
}


\starttext

\texsample{
\ConTeXt
}

\stoptext
```

and this is what I see when launch `ConTeXt`

```
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/third/filter/t-filter.mkiv
loading         > Filter (ver: 2013.04.15)
resolvers       > modules > 'module-catcodes' is loaded
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/third/filter/t-module-catcodes.tex
loading         > Module Catcodes (ver: 2011.12.17)
))
resolvers       > modules > 'syntax-highlight' is loaded
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/third/vim/t-syntax-highlight.mkiv
loading         > Code syntax highlighting (ver: 2012.08.01)
resolvers       > modules > 'syntax-groups' is loaded
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/third/vim/t-syntax-groups.tex
loading         > Syntax highlighting groups (ver: 2012.05.06)
resolvers       > modules > 'module-catcodes' is already loaded
)
resolvers       > modules > 'filter' is already loaded
))))
*
```

and nothing happens.

Comment: The standard way to do this is to use buffers. `\startbuffer ... \stopbuffer` to store content, `\typebuffer` to type it, and `\getbuffer` to process it. The vim module also allows you to typeset buffers (see documentation).

Comment: Did not understand how `\startbuffer` can help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to use buffers to typeset ConTeXt source.  To customize the layout of the typed buffer use `\setuptyping[buffer][...=...]`.

```
\starttext

\startbuffer[logo]
\ConTeXt
\stopbuffer

To typeset the \ConTeXt\ logo use
\typebuffer[logo][option=context]
\getbuffer[logo]

\stoptext
```

[image]